# How can I get characters for a password from the console but echo them as asterisks

Tags: c, input

I want to know how to take characters from the console using

```
scanf, getch()
```

or something else and at the time that the user gives the input I want the screen to show:

```
******
```

for every character.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, I think you can use something like given below -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(){
    char str[8];
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter the password :\n");
    while (i< 8){
        str[i]=getch();
        printf("*");
        i++;
    }
    str[i]='\0';
    return 0;
}
```

The `getch()` function is not so readily available on Unix-like systems.  (The `curses` or `ncurses` library provides a function `getch()`, but you have to call functions to setup the terminal correctly, and then reset it back to a known state.)